# Running a java class that inherits from other java classes using command line prompt

Tags: java, cmd, command-line, prompt, intellij-13

I'm trying to run a java class in IntelliJ, this class inherits from other classes in the same package and when I try to run it using command line prompt I get so many "cannot find symbols" errors.

My Java directory looks like this: [image]

My cmd command: `C:\Users\Musta\IdeaProjects\Prototype\src\test\java\org\example>javac LilacServer.java`

Comment: To compile all classes in folder and write the class files to a directory, use `javac -d bin src/test/java/org.example/*.java`. Then to run them, run by specifying a classpath `java -cp ./bin org.example.LilacServer`

Comment: @m_vemuri Thanks! as for the second part, could you specify where exactly should I run this command? (from the prototype folder or...?)

Comment: Run it where your bin directory has been created. That folder has the compiled binaries for the java files.